# log4j displaying log messages using %p

Tags: java, log4j

now for a particular log message for the %p sign i wil get either debug or error or warning. can anyone tel me how to get only the first three letters. eg. only WAR for Warning

Comment: Yes it does but its logging the last three letters . eg ING for warning

Comment: As a default it %.3p truncates from beginning. can anyone tel me how to truncate from the end

Comment: you might have to subclass PatternLayout

Comment: Thank u. im trying it out that way. pls let me know if u get a lead.

Comment: I think you will need to subclass PatternConvertor too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that executes the substring is in `org.apache.log4j.helpers.PatternConverter` class, `format` method:

```
if(len > max)
    sbuf.append(s.substring(len-max));
```

If you'd like to print out `WAR`, you should subclass `PatternConverter` class changing the substring line into `format` method to something like this:

```
if(len > max)
    sbuf.append(s.substring(0, max));
```

Then you should also write a new version of `PatternLayout#createPatternParser` method, which has to instantiate your new version of `PatternConverter`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

In log4j 2.x, you can truncate from the end:

> Truncation from the end is possible by appending a minus character
>   right after the period. In that case, if the maximum field width is
>   eight and the data item is ten characters long, then the last two
>   characters of the data item are dropped.

Link: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout

So in this case, `%.-3p` should give `WAR` instead of `WARNING`.